# What does this Path "file:///Users/..." mean?

Tags: java, path, uri

A Path constructor example from Java Tutorial:

```
Path p3 = Paths.get(URI.create("file:///Users/joe/FileTest.java"));
```

What does the part `URI.create("file:///Users/joe/FileTest.java")` means? I'm not familiar with URI synctax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means `file://` i.e the `file` at `/Users/joe/FileTest.java`.

Similar to other protocols, `http://` and `ftp://`, but the path starts with a `/` so it looks a little odd.

Comment: So the constructor is similar to `Path p3 = Paths.get("/Users/joe/FileTest.java");` isn't it? I wonder why they have to write the longer version including `URI.create("file://..."`

Answer (score 0):

You should check the javadoc, here is the snippet from that:

> create
>
> public static URI create(String str) Creates a URI by parsing the
>   given string. This convenience factory method works as if by invoking
>   the URI(String) constructor; any URISyntaxException thrown by the
>   constructor is caught and wrapped in a new IllegalArgumentException
>   object, which is then thrown.
>
> This method is provided for use in situations where it is known that
>   the given string is a legal URI, for example for URI constants
>   declared within in a program, and so it would be considered a
>   programming error for the string not to parse as such. The
>   constructors, which throw URISyntaxException directly, should be used
>   situations where a URI is being constructed from user input or from
>   some other source that may be prone to errors.
>
> Parameters: str - The string to be parsed into a URI Returns: The new
>   URI Throws: NullPointerException - If str is null
>   IllegalArgumentException - If the given string violates RFC 2396